# Flutter TextformField shows the ending of a sentence, instead of the beginning, after the submission

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I have a textformfield in my app and if the user types a long sentence and submits it, the textformfield still shows the ending part. Ideally I want the textformfield to goback and show the intial part of the sentece. Is it possible? Below is the code and after that shows, what I tried.

```
TextFormField(
                   
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    controller: _nameController,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,

     
                    },
                    validator: (text) {
                      return _nameFieldIsValid.value
                          ? null
                          : 'Enter  a valid name';
                    },
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30,
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),

                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: "name",
                      suffixIcon: _nameIsTyping
                          ? IconButton(
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined),
                              color: Colors
                                  .grey, 
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  _nameController.clear();
                                  _nameIsTyping = false;
                                });
                              },
                            )
                          : null,
                      hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                      labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                    ),
                  ),
The following is what I tried and didnt work:

idea1:

     onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                          _nameController.selection =
                              TextSelection.fromPosition(
                            TextPosition(offset: 0),
                          );
                         
                        },
```

Idea 2:

```
    onFieldSubmitted: (value) { 
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) { _nameController.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0); }
);
    },
```